# Issue while building eclipse project with gwt plug-in

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

I am facing an issue every time I am saving something in java file. I know the error message is coming from gwt plug-in.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/suite/preferences/GdtPreferences
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.ext.update.FeatureUpdateManager.checkForUpdates(FeatureUpdateManager.java:105)
at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.ext.builders.UpdateTriggerCompilationParticipant.isActive(UpdateTriggerCompilationParticipant.java:40)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$CompilationParticipants.getCompilationParticipants(JavaModelManager.java:339)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:587)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:167)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:299)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:302)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:358)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:381)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:143)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: What version of GPE are you using? We fixed a problem like this a few weeks back. Can you make sure you're at the latest version (3.4.2)?

Comment: I am using the latest version of google plug-in, I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Workaround solution that may work:](http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2013/02/errors-running-builder-google-webapp.html)

Close all projects, close eclipse.

Start eclipse using, "eclipse -clean" option.

You can try repeating the process 2-3 times,  if it does not work first time.

Not sure of the exact reason why this appears.

Comment: Thanks, Though the issue has been disappear after restarting my computer.

Comment: This didn't work for me in the end, I had to uninstall the gwt plugin.

Answer (score 4):

For me option -clean didn't help in every case though used several times. I found out that in my case the root cause of the NoClassDefError was a NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/suite/preferences/GdtPreferences
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.ext.update.FeatureUpdateManager.checkForUpdates(FeatureUpdateManager.java:105)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.markers.GdtProblemSeverities.loadSeverities(GdtProblemSeverities.java:144)
```

And when it occured in one workspace it occured in every workspace so I took a look into the Eclipse "installation". There is a file named

```
configuration/.settings/com.google.gdt.eclipse.suite.prefs
```

and it a line like this:

```
problemSeverities=com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.validators.rpc.RemoteServiceProblemType\#305\=1
```

After removing that link my Eclipse started without problems ... but with modified settings in Window/Preferences/Google ... I haven't found out how to specify those severity settings in the file to be parsed without an Exception.

Comment: This is the only solution that works. Added a comment to existing GWT issue https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/3841 referencing this post.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no such entry in the prefs for my Eclipse:
problemSeverities=com.google.gdt.eclipse.core.markers.ProjectStructureOrSdkProblemType\#706\=1|com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.markers.AppEngineProblemType\#207\=1|com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.markers.AppEngineProblemType\#207\=1